# LinkLists and nodes

Tags: java, linked-list

there is a project that I have been working on which requires me to create small social network site using java, which is run through IntellJ, all of the navigating is done through the console. I can do things like logon, create a new user, add friends and so on. However, part of the assignment requires me to create a linked list that allows me to 'like' websites. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is some of the methods that I have completed, but I am not sure at all how to build up my link lists to 'like' a webpage.The code I have attached has part of the menu and login system. I have been trying to work with nodes and linked lists, but to no avail. All help is appreciated.

```
  public class LoginRegistration
  {
  static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  private static User[] userAccount;
  private static User[] newUser;
  private static User newAccount;
  private static int noOfUsers = 0;

 protected static void menuPage()
 {
  int numberChoice;
  boolean menuChoice = false;

  System.out.println("Welcome to social network.");

  do
  {
     System.out.println("Existing user: Press '1'");
     System.out.println("Create a new account: Press '2'");
     System.out.println("Administrator: Press '3'");
     System.out.println("Press '4' to exit");
     numberChoice = keyboard.nextInt();

     keyboard.nextLine();
     switch (numberChoice)
     {
        case 1:
           loginPage();
           break;
        case 2:

           createNewAccount();
           break;
        case 3:
           System.out.println("\nSite Administrator");
           break;
        case 4:
           System.out.println("\nYou have chosen to Exit the system");
           break;
        default:
           System.out.println("\nInvalid choice");
     }//switch
  } while (numberChoice != 4);

  protected static void activitiesPage(User userOptions)
  {
  int numberChoice;

      "Welcome to your  account.\n What activity would you   
       like to do today?");
       "Please select one of the following:\n" +
          "Press '1' to search for another Gamer\n" +
          "Press '2' to edit your profile\n" +
          "Press '3' to like games, teams, gaming websites 
           and sports       websites\n" +

          "Press '6' to delete your account");
            System.out.println();


  do
  {
     numberChoice = keyboard.nextInt();

     keyboard.nextLine();
     switch (numberChoice)
     {
        case 1:

           searchForUser(userOptions.getUserEmail(),
      userOptions.getUserLastName());
           break;
        case 2:

           //edit profile
           break;
        case 3:
           //like websites
           break;
        case 4:
           //check sport websites
           break;

        case 5:
           //check gaming websites
           break;
        case 6:
           //delete account
           break;
        default:
           System.out.println("\nInvalid choice");
     }//switch
  } while (numberChoice != 6);
```

Comment: Java has a built-in java.util.LinkedList class. No need to reinvent the wheel. If your assignment asks you to implement it by yourself, then try something, show what you have tried and ask a concrete question. All the code you posted has nothing to do with linked lists.

Comment: Thanks for that, however, it is even getting the list of the ground, I am not sure how best to approach it in terms of layout, even where to start.

Comment: You use this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html